# What is the best way to loop while saving an object in(save it more than once) one click?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Lets say i have a model **Token** object with two fields ,**user_id** and **token_string**.I want to save the object more than once (basically looping) in one click,Everytime the object is saved is with same **user_id** but different **token_string** value.And later on i want to be able to retrieve all the token_strings saved by that particular user_id.The relationship is **User has_many Tokens** and **Token belongs_to User** .How do i do this? Much Thanks.

```
    def save_more_than_once
     #note here the object already has user_id value but nil token_string
     #loop start here,lets say loops couple of times
     self.token_string = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("random string")
     save!
     #loop end
     end
```

Comment: how many times do you want to save? And are you creating new tokens with each iteration?

Comment: @Chris more than once,might be any number and yes i want to create token in each iteration.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is

```
def make_a_bunch_of_tokens
  # code to set up user's ID here
  number_of_tokens.times do
    self.tokens.create!(token_string: Digest:SHA1.hexdigest("random string")
  end
  save!   # fixes the user's ID
end
```

Comment: Thank you ,that is what i want ,but i just tried for a number of tokens=2 but it only created one token_string

Comment: Ah, you mean that it make two tokens but they each had the same "random string?" You can either interpolate some random function there, or you can define what "random string" should be just above the `self.tokens.create` line. Or do I misunderstand the trouble?

Comment: I mean only one token object,i was expecting atleast to have two same token strings

Comment: That is odd. Are you using the bang on `create!`? If that fails to create something for some reason, it should error out. I know that sometimes object persistence throws me a curve ball in these situations; the second thing I'd try is `Token.create!(user_id: self.id, token_string: generated_token_string_goes_here)`.

Comment: I ran into some issues,now it says undefined method tokens

Comment: Most peculiar - can you post your updated code? I think something's changed in a significant way here and I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: i updated the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040827/no-method-error-when-trying-to-call-a-function-with-an-instantiated-object